# Query for graphics in PHPLOT

Tags: php, select, graphics, group-by, phplot

I'm trying to do one graphic in phpplot, I want to group by year and month all the register users in that time and show in a graphic that results.

In database is like that:

```
id  | utilizador | registado
----+------------+--------------------
1   |   crisutu  | 2014-05-04 10:41:53
2   |   blabla   | 2014-05-15 04:45:24
3   |   hello    | 2014-06-15 04:45:24
```

I want to transform in the graphic like MAY 2014 - 2 register users JUNE 2014 - 1 register user

```
<?php
#Incluimos a biblioteca
require("phplot-6.1.0/phplot.php");



#Definimos o objeto para inicar a "montagem" do gráfico
#Também delimitamos uma altura e largura do gráfico
$grafico = new PHPlot(750,600);

#Indicamos o formato de imagem a ser usado
$grafico->SetFileFormat("png");

#Indicamos o títul do gráfico e o título dos dados no eixo X e Y do mesmo
$grafico->SetTitle("NSMF");
$grafico->SetXTitle("Meses");
$grafico->SetYTitle("Utilizadores");


function getValues(){
  $db = new mysqli("xxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxx");
  $db->set_charset("utf8");
  $query = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(id),registado FROM utilizadores GROUP BY YEAR(registado), MONTH(registado) ");

  while($obj = $query->fetch_object()){

  $values[] = array($obj->id, $obj->id );

  }
  return $values;
  }

$dados = getValues();

$grafico->SetDataValues($dados);

#Exibimos o gráfico
$grafico->DrawGraph();
?>
```

Can you help me resolve the problem? Tell me what is wrong?

Comment: What is the error or current output?

Comment: Is the graphic empty.

Answer (score 0):

So here are three mistakes you made in your code:

### Accessing wrong property of object

I do believe that you are trying to access the property `id` of fetched object, but the property is actually `COUNT(id)`. You may consider using alias in the query, eg:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) as id, registrado ...
```

### Wrong data format

By default `PHPlot::setDataValues` expect following format:

```
array(
    array('key1', 'value11', 'value12'),
    array('key2', 'value21', 'value22'),
    array('key3', 'value31', 'value32'),
)
```

in your case `key`s are months so the first value of every array must be appropriate month, so write `$values[] = array($obj->registado, $obj->id );`, instead of `$values[] = array($obj->id, $obj->id );`

### Date formating

Finally for your date to appear in desired format use php function `date` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) when assigning values to `$value`. So use something like this:

```
$values[] = array(date("%F %Y", $obj->registado), $obj->id);
```

Comment: Is the same. Nothing change.

Comment: @ChristopheCosta OK, so offer a bit more feedback - What is content of `$dados` after calling `getValues()`, if it isn't what it supposed to be check SQL - dump content of `$db->error` after calling `$db->query` etc...

Comment: $dados call the function getValues() need to associate in one array (id count,(year,month)), for have the in graphic id versus (month/year), i try to get that fields in one table but the format is like id of the user(autoincrement) and registado have the datetime like (2012-02-02 00:00:00). I want only get the month and year and transform that for in output in graphic be like February of 2012 have 5 users registered. Maybe have another way to do but i think that is correct and something i am forgetting...........

Comment: @ChristopheCosta Yeah, I kind of know what are you trying to do. And I noticed another one mistake - I believe you should write `$values[] = array($obj->registado, $obj->id );`, instead of `$values[] = array($obj->id, $obj->id );` But if we are to help you, you have to provide more information - as I said before, for example content of `$dados` - just write `var_dump($dados)` after calling `getValues()` function and let us know what is the resut - this way we will know if there is problem in using `PHPlot` or somewhere else...

Comment: Hello,i change what you tell. Change array and now is almost perfect... That is the result about vardump array(3) { [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(19) "2014-05-04 10:41:53" [1]=> string(1) "7" } [1]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(19) "2014-07-26 10:02:27" [1]=> string(1) "3" } [2]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(19) "2014-08-27 12:16:15" [1]=> string(1) "4" } }  In graphic appears the date normal(2014-05-04 10:00:00) and not May 2014, what you suggest to do?

Comment: @ChristopheCosta: I edited my answer in case anyone else will look for it - see the third part for your code to be complete. Next time you may do some debugging by yourself (questions of type "here is my question - what's wrong?" isn't usually answered.

Comment: You are right, sorry for the mistake. I already do debug about the problema and is giving the same problem in another graphics, is giving December 1969 in formate date for all months......

Comment: Output: array(3) { [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(15) "%December %1969" [1]=> string(1) "7" } [1]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(15) "%December %1969" [1]=> string(1) "3" } [2]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(15) "%December %1969" [1]=> string(1) "4" } }

Comment: @ChristopheCosta I'm confused - are you now describing this code? If so, I do not really know, why it is giving you such output, if not it may be good idea to start a new question

Comment: No, is the output for the graphic (vardump of dados). In graphic, one axis is giving DECEMBER 1969 in all rows and that is not correct. i try already put strtotime and see some examples in stakeoverflow.

Comment: I'm sorry I do not understand you. If it's still related to the code you wrote here, update your question according your new findings (so it'll be a appropriate place), if not start a new question